# Can we encode 6 byte integer to 4 byte integer?

Tags: c

My Application (C code) receives a 4 byte integer from some external module and further uses it throughout application. Now this module sends me a 6 byte integer but I cannot change my application and want to have some way of encoding the received 6 byte it to 4 byte, So that my application can seamlessly work.

Comment: What you're asking would basically mean (via induction) that you could compress *anything* into 1 single bit.

Comment: What if the integer is too large to be represented in 32 bits? If you know that it will be between `-2^31` and `2^31 - 1`, just use a cast.

Comment: Ignoring the two lowest-order bytes might be an option, but there is definitely not enough context to tell.

Comment: The counting theorem states that you cannot encode arbitrary data with fewer bits than it occupies uncompressed. Now if you had a reduction function which removes enough redundant information to reduce your data containing at most 4 byte of entropy to 4 bytes... If it contains more, perhaps you use it as an index into a side-table with the actual data...

Comment: @TimČas beware of over-generalization. You don't know the context.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Well, it could be done *lossy*, yes; or lossless if he's just trying to save space during transmission (by encoding more common values using fewer bits, like some sort of Huffman coding)

Comment: Yes, I agree if 5th and 6th byte can be ignored it should work for me but I don't have any surety for this. Not sure if there's any such compression algorithm that can compress 6 byte to 4 byte.

Comment: @SandeepArora: There is no such compression algorithm that works for arbitrary inputs.

Comment: There are plenty algorithms for compressing 6 bytes down to 4. But they are either lossy, or they need intimate knowledge of your input and a guarantee that no more than 4 byte worth of inputs are actually possible.

Comment: What does this 6 byte integer represent?

Comment: 6 byte is struct with 2 byte as Identifier type and 4 byte as identifier index.

Comment: @SandeepArora: Are there actually 2**16 possible identifier types and 2**32 possible identifier indices? *Please* update your question with more information about your requirements; your question cannot be meaningfully answered as it stands.

Comment: @SandeepArora: It's a fundamental impossibility. 6 bytes mean 48 bits of information (assuming 8-bit bytes). 4 bytes mean 32 bits of information. You cannot encode 48 bits of information using 32 bits (without losses, that is).

Comment: Thanks everyone, sorry that most of experts felt I didn't provide detailed information, will take care for this further on. As of now, I am convinced that practically its not possible with any lossless algorithm. I feel I need to change my application to support 6 bytes. Thanks once again everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly encode a 6-byte number in 4 bytes, but it's mathematically impossible to recover the original number in all cases.

If the 6-byte inputs have 2<sup>32</sup> possible values (meaning that the vast majority of possible 6-byte inputs will never appear), then you can do it. If the 2<sup>32</sup> you're going to get happen to be representable in 32 bits, then problem is nearly trivial, though we'd need more information about just how the numbers are represented. (For example, are the high-order 2 bytes always zero?) If there are 2<sup>32</sup> or fewer possible inputs but they're scattered across the range of 48-bit numbers, then you'll need to do some kind of non-trivial encoding -- and in that case we'd need a *lot* more information than you've given us.

I'm assuming here that a "byte" is 8 bits; that's the most common meaning of the term, but it's not universal.

If you have a reasonably modern C compiler, then you can use type `long long`, which is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits (8 bytes). You say you cannot change your application, but that doesn't make sense; changing your application is the only way you're going to be able to accomplish anything at all. If you mean that you can't change certain properties of your application, then again, you're going to have to give us more information.

Comment: Perhaps mention the possibility of using 4-byte handles, as the restriction seems to be only in the application...

Comment: [Counting argument on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_compression_algorithm#Limitations)

Comment: @Deduplicator: I don't know what you mean by "4-byte handles".

Comment: He said "want to have some way of encoding the received 6 byte it to 4 byte, so that my application can seamlessly work", so it might be only for internal forwarding. So, Using a handle representing the actual data might be possible...

Comment: @Deduplicator: Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its highly impossible.

Anyway you need to modify your application to hold 6 byte integer. I know the changes migbt be huge. But using customized build-in data type alias (with macros or typedef) will helps to handle these kind of situations with minimal code changes. At least function prototypes will not get changed.

old code

```
typedef int MY_INT;
func(MY_INT a)
{
    //doing operation on a
}
```

This code needs to modify as below to hold 6 byte integer.

```
typedef long long MY_INT;
func(MY_INT a)
{
    //doing operation on a
}
```

Comment: Please read [Keith Thompson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24717005/3204551).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do so without the risk of losing some information.  With a 6 byte integer, you have a larger number of possible values than is supported with a 4 byte integer.  This means that for every 4 byte integer, you can construct an equivalent 6 byte integer; but for every 6 byte integer, it is not possible to construct a 4 byte integer.

With 6 bytes, you have an upper limit of 2.8147498e+14 possible byte combinations.  With 4 bytes, you have an upper limit of 4294967296 possible byte combinations.  Moving from 6 bytes to 4 bytes, the 4294967297th and above combinations will have to be discarded.  By discarding those combinations, it will not be a "perfect" interoperability because some of the inputs won't have an equivalent in the 4 byte system.

Comment: you forgot unique or dedicated for both.